# Move tmux status bar to the very bottom of my screen

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to display the tmux status-bar at the very bottom of my monitor and not have the 1cm gap between it and the bottom of my screen?

I looked online and could only see the queries regarding displaying different things within the status-bar but not configuring the status-bar itself.

Thanks

Comment: If you start tmux in a xterm, does it still display the gap?

Comment: Ah, yes a small gap too in xterm @bjanssen. Good point. I'm using straight up Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu. In full-screen in Terminal there's a slighly smaller gap, so I guess I'll settle for that. Just with the other applications open within tmux, I was wondering if can reclaim some more real-estate. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Edit ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css and add the following to remove padding:

```
VteTerminal,
vte-terminal,
TerminalScreen {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  -VteTerminal-inner-border: 0px;
}
```